# Froala image manager doesn't show images after request to the server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, froala

Asp.net core MVC. Using the editor and send a request to the server to get a list of files already uploaded to the server. But Froala edit manager returns critical error.

Froala editor settings:

```
// Set the load images request URL
        imageManagerLoadURL: "/GetUploadedList",
        // Set the load images request type
        imageManagerLoadMethod: "POST",
        // Set page size
        imageManagerPageSize: 20,
        // Set a scroll offset (value in pixels)
        imageManagerScrollOffset: 10
    })
        .on('froalaEditor.imageManager.error', function (e, editor, error, response) {
            // Custom error message returned from the server.
            if (error.code === 0) { alert("error"); }

            // Bad link.
            else if (error.code === 1) { alert("bad link"); }

            // No link in upload response.
            else if (error.code === 2) { alert("no link"); }

            // Error during image upload.
            else if (error.code === 3) { alert("during image"); }

            // Parsing response failed.
            else if (error.code === 4) { alert("parsing error"); }

            // Image too large.
            else if (error.code === 5) { alert("large image"); }

            // Invalid image type.
            else if (error.code === 6) { alert("invalid image"); }

            // Image can be uploaded only to same domain in IE 8 and IE 9.
            else if (error.code === 7) { alert("ie8 error"); }
        })
```

Method asp:

```
[HttpPost("GetUploadedList")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult UploadedList()
{
    string[] listFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploadedImages/admin"));

    List<object> jsonListFiles = new List<object>();

    //List<object> jsonListFiles = new List<object>()
    //{
    //    new { src = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo1.jpg" },
    //    new { src = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo2.jpg" },
    //    new { src = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo3.jpg" }
    //};

    //List<object> jsonListFiles = new List<object>()
    //{
    //    new { url = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo1.jpg", thumb = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo1.jpg", tag = "pencils", name = "Photo 1 Name", id = "10545464" },
    //    new { url = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo2.jpg", thumb = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo2.jpg", tag = "musician", name = "Photo 2 Name", id = "4532453453" },
    //    new { url = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo3.jpg", thumb = "https://www.froala.com/assets/editor/media_files/photo3.jpg", tag = "umbrella", name = "Photo 3 Name", id = "4345348889" }
    //};

    foreach (var item in listFiles)
    {
        jsonListFiles.Add(new
        {
            name = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1),
            url = item,
            thumb = item,
            tag = "uploadedImages/admin"
        });
    }

    var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonListFiles);

    return Json(jsonObj);
}
```

On the site itself, the editor issued the format of the returned data, as:

```
[
  {
    "url": "http://exmaple.com/images/photo1.jpg",
    "thumb": "http://exmaple.com/thumbs/photo1.jpg",
    "tag": "flower"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://exmaple.com/images/photo2.jpg",
    "thumb": "http://exmaple.com/thumbs/photo2.jpg",
    "tag": "sport"
  }
]
```

However, it produces a script error. 
[image]

Comment: How about using `@Url.Action()` to build the controller and action name? I can't understand why the URL has `undefined` instead of action name.

Comment: I use the syntax and rules of the editor. The editor works only this way, the request is sent, the data is returned, however, after the data is returned, they are not displayed